# Recommendations on WPF Drag & Drop library

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls

I'm using [GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop library](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/) now. It works with MVVM, supports multiple selections, works with TreeViews... But it has a few annoying bugs. And it has not been updated since Dec 2009.

Any alternatives?

Edit: Changed title for better description.

Comment: 12 months on, did you ever find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to fix the bugs.  It's open source, so it might be worth it (especially if it's baked into your code base already).

Comment: Actually I've already done that. I changed a few lines of code to workaround the issues. But I'm not sure if my workaround would cause side-effects (I don't have much programming experiences).